# load vector inside a vector class (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, class, vector

So I need to use a vector class for my program. The user defines the size of it, and basically that means 'amount of students'to be processed since i have to receive name, id number, and their answers in a test. Then I have to compare said answers to the right ones, determine his grade (if it's above 70% he/she passed). I'm confused about the constructor because I can't seem to send the values (answers) to my class and thus compare them, so students always fail and get a '0'. Here's what I got (I'm a noob :c):

```
import java.io.*;
class vector
{
private String nom, ced;//name and id
private String[] res = new String [12];//answers

vector (String n, String c)
{
    nom = n;
    ced = c;
}
vector (String tab[])
{
    res = tab;  
}

public String nombre()//name
{
    return nom;
}
public String cedula()//id
{
    return ced;
}
public int puntaje()//score
{
    String[] clv= {"b","c","a","b","d","a","c","d","a","b","c","d"};//right answers
    int x,acum=0;
    for(x=0;x<12;x++)
    {
        if(res[x]==clv[x])
            acum=acum+1;
    }
    return acum;
}
public String resultado()//result
{
    double nota;
    String msg;
    nota = puntaje()*100/12;
    if(nota>=70)
       msg = ("APROBÓ!" + nota);//pass
    else
        msg = ("FRACASÓ!" + nota);//fail
    return msg;
}
}




public class pizza //sorry
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
  int size;
  System.out.println("Numero de estudiantes que tomaron la prueba ---> ");//# of students
  size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  vector [] objnc = new vector[size];
  int i, j;
  String nom, ced, r;
  String [] resp = new String [12];

  try
  { 
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre ---> ");//name
    nom = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cédula ---> ");//id
    ced = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese las respuestas: ---> ");//answers
    for(j=0;j<12;j++)
    {
        r = br.readLine();
        br.skip(1);
        resp[j] = r;
        vector objc = new vector(resp);

    }

    objnc[i] = new vector(nom,ced);
  }
 }
 catch(NumberFormatException z)
    {   System.out.println("Error de conversion... "+z);
    }
    catch(IOException z)
    { System.out.println("Error de entrada/salida... "+z);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException z)
    { System.out.println("Error de lectura... "+z);
    }
    catch(Exception z)
    { System.out.println("Error... "+z);
    }         

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    System.out.println(objnc[i].nombre()+"  "+objnc[i].cedula()+"  "+objnc[i].resultado());

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Haha, too bad for your students ;)

You should create a separate class called Student. In this student class, add variables for name, id number, and answers. Next, add a method to your vector class called checkGrades(). This method should take a student object as an argument. In this method, write the code that checks the individual student's grades. Return true or false if he passed/failed.

Then create all of the student objects you need in the same file where you create the vector object. *Ex: Student student1 = new Student(fill in the parameters)*

Once you have created all your students, use your vector's checkGrades(), passing a student object as an argument to check whether each individual student passed.